# Downloaded videos with urllib and bs4 does not play

Tags: python, django, urllib2, urllib, beautifulsoup

I have a folder online where I have video files so I need to download videos from there to my local system so in order to do that I am using **Bs4** , **urllib** modules , The downloaded files are not playable

Please have a look at my code .

```js
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import random
import urllib
from urllib2 import urlopen
         
def download(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen("http://ssdolutions/addadsfasdfulsdfaatadfae")
    doc  = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        x = (link.get('href'))
        name = random.randrange(1,10)
        full_name = str(name) + ".mp4"
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
download("http://ssdolutions/addadsfasdfulsdfaatadfae")
```

Comment: Try opening downloaded file with a text editor and check what's inside. I suspect you files are empty or have HTML inside.

Comment: ya I did it and found like the file was downloading in mp4 format but when i opened in text editor it was a html page .

Comment: This means that you are making something wrong. Try opening that downloaded file in a browser and take a look what is written there - maybe there is a message like "page not found" or "you don't have permissions to view this file".

Comment: The code is wrong I'm retrieving **href** and storing them as **mp4** files. I need a solution where i can download all mp4 files present in a url at a time and store in local directory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass every link URL (stored in `x` variable) to `urlretrieve` call:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import random
import urllib
import os
from urllib2 import urlopen

def download(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen("http://ssdolutions/addadsfasdfulsdfaatadfae")
    doc  = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        url = (link.get('href'))
        # Extract filename from link URL
        filename = os.path.basename(url)
        file_data = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if len(file_data) > 1:
           file_ext = file_data[1]
           # this will allow you to download links with *.mp4 extension only
           if file_ext == ".mp4":
              urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)

download("http://ssdolutions/addadsfasdfulsdfaatadfae")
```

Comment: I have to add filename also

Comment: + small bonus that will download mp4 files only, no all links form a page.